# Hygieia collectors not working

Tags: docker, sonarqube, hygieia

Good Morning,

I'm currently unable to get any of the listeners working to display data in the Hygieia dashboard. Right now I'm just trying to get sonar results displayed. The sonar instance is up and running at localhost:9000 with scan results.

My compose file looks like the following:

```
mongodb:
  image: mongo:latest
  container_name: mongodb
  command: mongod --smallfiles
  ports:
   - "27017:27017"
  volumes:
   - ./mongo:/var/lib/mongo/:rw
  volume_driver: local
hygieia-api:
  image: hygieia-api:latest
  container_name: hygieia-api
  ports:
  - "8080:8080"
  volumes:
  - ./logs:/hygieia/logs
  links:
  - mongodb:mongo
hygieia-ui:
  image: hygieia-ui:latest
  container_name: hygieia-ui
  ports:
  - "8088:80"
  links:
  - hygieia-api


hygieia-sonar-codequality-collector:
  image: hygieia-sonar-codequality-collector:latest
  container_name: hygieia-sonar-codequality
  volumes:
  - ./logs:/hygieia/logs
  links:
  - mongodb:mongo
  - hygieia-api
```

My override file:

```
hygieia-sonar-codequality-collector:
  environment:
  - SONAR_CRON=*/1 * * * *
  - SONAR_URL=http://localhost:9000
  - SONAR_API=http://localhost:9000/api/projects/index/
```

My application.properties file:

```
dbname=dashboard
dbhost=localhost
dbport=27017
dbusername=dashboarduser
dbpassword=dbpassword
sonar.cron=0 0/5 * * * *
sonar.servers[0]=http://localhost:9000
sonar.metrics=ncloc,line_coverage,violations,critical_violations,major_violations,blocker_violations,sqale_index,test_success_density,test_failrues,test_errors,tests
```

I've had the same issue with JIRA and Jenkins as well and have not been able to get any test results into the dashboard. Thank you for any help.

EDIT:
2017-03-08 17:34:32,007 ERROR c.c.d.collector.DefaultSonarClient - org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://0.0.0.0:9000/api/resources?format=json":Connect to 0.0.0.0:9000 [/0.0.0.0] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 0.0.0.0:9000 [/0.0.0.0] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)

This seems to be my issue, however I am able to connect to the above url successfully..

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my issue by pointing to the ip address of the container instead of localhost.